# NGO for VR packets jitter in local network

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, networking, virtual-reality

I have an VR Escape Room with the software developend by me. I use a PC as Host and 8 Meta quest 2 for the players. The game is ful local, i use internet only to download initial validation data and to sent user collect data.

I developed it with unity 2022.1.19, NGO, Unet transport and everything work well.

Now i have updated unity to 2022.3.2 LTS, NGO to 1.5.1 and use Unity Transport 1.3.4 (tryed with 2.0 too) and here starts the problems:

Evrything starts lagging, even if i am on a local network (we use netgear orbi pro wifi6 routers) but not always, only when players mooves a bit or turn around, if the players stays without mooving it is all smooth.

The meta quest 2 is not overloaded, cpu usage around 40% e gpu usage around 70%.

The fun fuct is that the Quest 2 i use only for dev is always smooth but all the others, with the same settings and the same software have this problem. The more fun fuct is that in the other office, with the same software, pc, router and headset all headsets works smooth...

in my tests i see that when is smooth the headset sends X packets, but when start mooving and so start lagging it stop sending packets for a fraction of secods then arrive all the packets togheter causing this lag effect...

I've been trying to solve this problem for a week working on it night and day but nothing to do ... I'm going crazy ... if does anyone have any suggestions saves my life.

I really don't understand how on one headset everything is fine, and on the others with the same software and settings there is this problem...